# How is the determinant being used here?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I seem to be missing something very basic about determinants. I am studying Neukirch, and the relevant part of an argument I'm not getting is outlined below.

$A$ is an integrally closed integral domain with field of fractions $K$. $L/K$ is a finite separable extension with ring of integers $B$. We are assuming $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in B$ is a basis for $L/K$ with $d=\text{disc}(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$. We have to show $dB \subseteq \sum_i{A\alpha_i}$.

Neukirch argues: Let $\alpha\in B$ be $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\alpha_i$ for $a_i\in K$. Then since the trace function $\text{Tr}_{L/K}(xy)$ is a bilinear form, the $a_i$ are a solution of the system
$$\text{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha) = \sum_{j=1}^n \text{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha_j)a_j.$$ We also know $\text{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha)\in A$. All good till here. But then he concludes: so the $a_i$ are given as the quotient of an element of $A$ by the determinant $\text{det}(\text{Tr}(\alpha_i\alpha_j))=d$. How does the determinant enter the picture here?

Again, I know this is very basic, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that $A^{-1} = (\det A)^{-1} \mathsf{adj}(A)$, so if a matrix $A$ has coefficients in some ring $R$; the coefficients of $A^{-1}$ are in $ \det(A)^{-1} R$

Comment: Yes, of course, totally forgot about that relation. Thanks!